# Autohotkey iterate through loop, but only return value if key matches input

Tags: autohotkey

Suppose I have the following

```
^!r::
  InputBox, input, Enter the string
  if (input = "trip")
  {
    TripFunction()
  }
  else if (input = "leave")
  {
    LeaveFunction()
  }
  else
  {
    Msgbox, That word isnt defined.
  }
Return
```

But, anticipating having to add a lot of different cases to test for, I figure the best idea is to put this into an array, and iterate through the array, looking for the matching key, returning the value (the function), and no longer iterating through the dictionary. So now, I have something like this:

```
^!r::
  InputBox, input, Enter the string
  dict = { "trip": TripFunction(), "leave": LeaveFunction() }
  for k, v in dict
  {
    ...
    see if k = "trip", if so, return TripFunction(), if not, go to next
    item in array
    ...
  }
Return
```

The trouble I'm having is once it successfully matches akey in the dictionary, it will return all of the associated values. What should I put in the brackets to do what I intend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong [equal sign operator](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Intro) (use `:=` for non-literal assignments instead of `=`)

Also, in the line `dict = { "trip": TripFunction(), "leave": LeaveFunction() }`, tripfunction aind leavefunction are executed, which you probably do not want.

Try:

```
^!r::
  InputBox, input, Enter the string
  dict := { "trip": "TripFunction", "leave": "LeaveFunction" }
  for k, v in dict
  {
    if(k==input) {
        %v%() ; documentation: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#DynCall
        break
    }
  }
Return

TripFunction() {
    msgbox trip
}

LeaveFunction() {
    msgbox leave
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'd intended. Your example makes it clear how use and mention works in autohotkey. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Mario well you're welcome! xD you might wanna consider accepting this answer then or others will see the question as unsolved